# createMany equivalent for updateOrCreate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a `createMany` equivalent for `updateOrCreate` in Laravel for when you want to "updateOrCreate" many records in one call?

In other words, is there a sort of `updateOrCreateMany` function?

From the documentation there doesn't appear to be a function with that name, but maybe there's another friendly Laravel way of doing this... or should I just use a `foreach` (maybe also using MySQL's [insert on duplicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same issue just now and I searched everywhere and couldn’t get a valid solution until I went through [the Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts). Laravel has an `upsert` method for that. Instead of having `updateOrCreate` in a loop, you can easily use the upsert method like this:

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

The `upsert` method accepts 2 parameters, the first is the array of the data you want to change, and the second is an array of the columns you want to use to check the uniqueness. The method's third and final argument is an array of the columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database.

Comment: Not sure your example follows the documentation so I've edited it, but thanks for alerting me to the existence of the `upsert()` method!

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ChuckLeButt
I actually used the data in the question for the answer and not the data in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any data in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Based upon the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) of Laravel, no there is no method on eloquent like `updateOrCreateMany`

If you give it a thought, it makes sense because the execution will anyway need to be sequential. As its possible that some entry might affect the previous one so the insertion or updation mode cannot be concurrent. So even if there was some method like that, it would anyway use a loop internally to execute query one by one.

To clear further let's say there was a method `updateOrCreateMany` which would probably take input like array of arrays like so:

```
Model::updateOrCreateMany([
   [
      'email' => 'x@y.com'
   ],
   [
      'email' => 'x2@y2.com'
   ],
   [
      'email' => 'x@y.com'
   ]
],
[
   [
      'name' => 'X Y'
   ],
   [
      'name' => 'X2 Y2'
   ],
   [
      'name' => 'X Y Updated'
   ]
]);
```

As you can see that record 3 is supposed to update the record 1 so basically, you cannot enter all at once by only comparing each with the database image of the insertion time of record1, that way you will enter in error of duplicated email as `x@y.com` did not exist initially.

Hence, there is no `updateOrCreateMany` method because it cannot be done concurrent, it needs to be sequential which means some kind of looping mechanism like foreach.

By the way Good Question! +1

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but the `createMany` method doesn't work with data in the format you've suggested, and neither does the `updateOrCreate` method. There would be no technical limitations with looping through the `updateOrCreate` method, I just wondered if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Really? `updateOrCreate` doesn't work with the data in the format I suggested? :) OK so how does it exactly work? Please enlighten me..as far as I knew, it accepts two parameters, both arrays...first to match and second for update `updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])`, the same way I tried to construct `updateOrCreateMany` with two arrays but as its a Many, it will be 2D arrays same as `insert` method. Here is a reference for you: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate

Comment: @ChuckLeButt PS, `createMany` works exactly the same as `insert`, takes one parameter of 2D array..Of course there is no second parameter because you don't need to match with anything...i dont know what you meant by `but the createMany method doesn't work with data in the format you've suggested`, of course :) createMany does not need an additional parameter for matching

Comment: Just clarify what I meant: `updateOrCreate` accepts two arrays, not one. There first is what it looks to match in the table, the second are the values to update if it finds them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a foreach loop on your data and using updateOrCreate method

```
foreach($records as $record){
   Model::updateOrCreate([$record->id, $record->name], [$record->likes, $record->dislikes]);
}
```